# Typescript compiler can't infer type from Promise resolve call

Tags: typescript, types

When using the following snippet, the compiler can't identify the types for `item1`, it will assign as unknown (see when hovering to the var name on the [Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/MYewdgzgLgBA5gUygSSggtjAvDAFASmwD4BYAKBhjAQHcYAFAJxHQEsIFddGEIQAbAG4JCWIjADe5SpR5QArozAwefIZwDkAQxhRWUfgg34A3NJgBfU+XK4tEAJ5hgMAGbzne8AUnnQkWH0MAEZsGC0aLX14JFQMAjMKGH9oGCD0ACYwiKjYRBQ0dATyK2KyIA)

Why isn't typescript compiler able to infer that type will be a string?

```js
    const getItem = () =>
      new Promise((resolve) => {
        return resolve('a title');
      });
    
    (async function() {
      const item1 = await getItem();
      const item2 = await getItem();
    })();
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The issue is that the type of the Promise can't be inferred from the type passed to the resolve method.  The resolve method gets its type from the generic type passed to the Promise constructor, not the other way around.  Also you don't need to use `return` with resolve in this case.

You can address this in one of two ways.

1. You should pass `string` as the generic type parameter.  Use `Promise<string>((resolve) => { ...`, which will tell typescript that you expect a string to be passed to the `resolve` function.  You will see a type error if you try to call `resolve` with something else.
2. You can use a construction like `Promise.resolve('a title');` if you aren't actually awaiting anything and just want to wrap a string in a promise.  This way, the generic type parameter can be inferred.